# Algorithm for data clustering based on clustered data

Tags: algorithm, data-science, cluster-analysis, data-analysis, k-means

Let's say I have a set of *X* entities, which have been clustered into *K* clusters *N* times.
For example, let's assume *X = 9*, *K = 3* and *N = 4* and:

1. `{a,b,c}`, `{d,e,f}`, `{g,h,i}`
2. `{c,d}`, `{a,b,f,i}`, `{e,g,h}`
3. `{d,g,i}`, `{a,f}`, `{b,c,e,h}`
4. `{a}`, `{b,c,d,e,f,i}`, `{g,h}`

are the 4 *clusterings* of 9 items into 3 clusters each. I am now looking for an algorithm to form  a **single clustering** of *X* entities into *k* clusters based on given *N* clusterings (based on how many times an entity was clustered with another one). For example let's say that in our example a correct clustering would be:

`{a,b,c,d}`, `{e,f,i}`, `{g,h}`

I would be grateful for any algorithms / notions that would point me to possible solutions.

---

**[EDIT]** I will add information about the specific problem I want to solve with this approach.

I have *N* test problems.
And I have an algorithm which outputs solutions in form of sequences to a given problem. This algorithm has many parameters and say there is *X* combinations of possible parameters. Now, I want to perform further experiments, but cannot afford to experiment with all *X* combinations, and want to choose *K* meaningful combinations. By meaningful I mean producing most diverse solutions.

My idea was: take 1 problem, generate output for all *X* combinations of parameters, then cluster the outputs into *K* clusters based on how similar they were. Then, if I was interested in 1 problem only, I would just simply take one output from each cluster and the associated parameter combinations would be the chosen *K* combinations.

But I want to do it for **ALL** *N* test problems. So I would have all *X* combinations, clustered into *K* clusters *N* times. And now I wanted to create final *K* clusters based on the previous.

I would not want to simply choose one clustering over another, but rather create a new one, which based on all previous ones.

Comment: Pick the one with the smallest residual?

Comment: Thanks @CarySwoveland. I edited the post to include more information on what specifically I wanted to achieve. I would not want to just simply pick one clustering, since it would then be based on a single problem instead of all of them. And I think the final clustering must somehow reflect on "how many times an entity was clustered with another one".

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is what you're looking for. At the end is a list of what I get. I'm not sure how to go further from the list because combinations with the same count doesn't mean all elements in those combinations were clustered together for the same time.
e.g. (a,b),(a,f),(b,f) all clustered together twice, but (a,b,f) are only clustered once.

```
# create list from clustered data
lst1 = [{'a','b','c'}, {'d','e','f'}, {'g','h','i'}]
lst2 = [{'c','d'}, {'a','b','f','i'}, {'e','g','h'}]
lst3 = [{'d','g','i'}, {'a','f'}, {'b','c','e','h'}]
lst4 = [{'a'}, {'b','c','d','e','f','i'}, {'g','h'}]

# create list of all lists
lst0 = [lst1, lst2, lst3, lst4]

# exhaust possible combinations
from itertools import combinations

lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
comb = list(combinations(lst, 2))

# count how many times each combination has been grouped together 

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

count = pd.DataFrame({'combination': comb, 'count': 0})

N = len(lst0) # N = 4
K = len(lst1) # K = 3

for i in range(len(count)):
  for j in range(N):
    for k in range(K):
      if ((count.combination[i][0] in lst0[j][k]) and (count.combination[i][1] in lst0[j][k])):
        count.loc[i, 'count'] += 1
```

Edit: showing only first 12 instead of full list

| index | combination | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a,b | 2 |
| 1 | a,c | 1 |
| 2 | a,d | 0 |
| 3 | a,e | 0 |
| 4 | a,f | 2 |
| 5 | a,g | 0 |
| 6 | a,h | 0 |
| 7 | a,i | 1 |
| 8 | b,c | 3 |
| 9 | b,d | 1 |
| 10 | b,e | 2 |
| 11 | b,f | 2 |

Comment: Thanks for your input. I feel that this is the correct direction, but it does not product the final clusters that I need.